# How to merge or join two tables by matching multiple indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

[here's the screen shot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PDwx.png)

I used groupby to group by date and id to count the occurrences of two trips. Now, I have two tables with the different number of rows. I want to merge the two tables together and place 0 on the missing ones (since the rows don't match).

```
count_new1 = 
    merge_id.groupby(['starttime','from_station_id'])['trip_id']‌​.
        aggregate(['count']‌​)
```

I use groupby twice to count the trips to and from a station during a day.

```
count_from ['count_from']=   
    df.groupby(['starttime','from_station_id'])['trip_id'].
        aggre‌​gate(['count']) 
count_stop['count_stop'] = 
    df.groupby(['stoptime','to_station_id'])['trip_id'].
        aggregat‌​e(['count'])
```

How can I match up the `from_station_id` and `to_station_id` and merge the two tables?

Comment: Would be really helpful if you can add a sample code block of your dataframes.

Comment: `count_new1 = merge_id.groupby(['starttime','from_station_id'])['trip_id'].aggregate(['count'])`

Comment: hope this link help https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Please put the code and data in your question so we can help. For example build 2 sample dataframes pd.Dataframe([{}])... External links with code are not welcomed.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga I'm sorry. I'm still a noobie here. I uploaded the picture and it shows up as a link. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @Wen Thanks for the link! I figured it out!

Comment: Now I have an another question followed up with the previous questions. I use groupby twice to count the trips to and from a station during a day. `count_from ['count_from']= df.groupby(['starttime','from_station_id'])['trip_id'].aggregate(['count'])`
'count_stop['count_stop'] = df.groupby(['stoptime','to_station_id'])['trip_id'].aggregate(['count'])'
how can I match up the "from_station_id" and "to_station_id" and merge the two tables?

Comment: pd.merge(DF1,DF2,left_on='from_station_id',right_on='to_station_id',how='left')